# Tensorflow js - weights and biases not updated by optimizer iterations

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to create a simple logistic regression model using tensorflow js. I am using some synthesised data and then calling a train function which houses all the of the logic. I am also only using the `core` api.

The code is as follows:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-core');

const NUM_OF_CLASSES = 1;
const NUM_OF_EXAMPLES = 1000;
const NUM_OF_VARIABLES = 300;
const NUM_EPOCHS = 10;

function compute_X(N, D) {
  return tf.randomNormal([N, D], 0.0, 1.0);
}

function compute_y(X) {
  const stepData = tf.tidy(
    () => tf.step(tf.slice2d(X, [0,0], [X.shape[0],1])).reshape([-1])
  );
  return stepData;
}

const X = compute_X(NUM_OF_EXAMPLES, NUM_OF_VARIABLES);
const y = compute_y(X);

function train(X, y) {

  const w = tf.variable(tf.zeros([NUM_OF_VARIABLES, NUM_OF_CLASSES]));
  const b = tf.variable(tf.zeros([NUM_OF_CLASSES]))

  const model = x =>
    x.matMul(w)
      .add(b)
      .softmax()
      .as1D();

  const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.1 /* learningRate */);

  for (let epoch = 0; epoch < NUM_EPOCHS; epoch++) {
    //b.print()
    optimizer.minimize(() => {
      const predYs = model(X);
      predYs.data().then(d => console.log('predYs', d));
      y.data().then(d => console.log('y', d));
      const loss = tf.losses.meanSquaredError(y, predYs);
      loss.data().then(l => console.log('Loss', l));
      return loss;
    }, true, [b, w]);
  }
}

train(X, y);
```

Each iteration is performing the exact same calculation and the create variables `b` & `w` are not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the model function to use `sigmoid()` and all is working!

Not 100% sure why using `softmax()` meant the model was not able to optimise the weights and biases.